# Angular : ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my code , i take it from w3school.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "sparsh";
        $scope.lastName = "khandelwal";
    });
</script>
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-init="name='Sparsh'">
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">{{firstName}}</div>
        <p>
            Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name">
        </p>
        <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    </div>

    <div ng-app="" ng-init="names=['Jani','Hege','Kai']">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names">{{x}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

ng-repeat in second block is not working.

here is the output i get on browser
[image]

Please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular only bootstraps the first found application on the page, i.e. the first container with `ng-app` attribute. The second one you put, `ng-app=""` will be ignored. Although, you could manually bootstrap the second one with `angular.bootstrap` method, in your case it makes more sense to wrap entire `body` into the same app and remove the second `ngApp` directive:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div  ng-init="name='Sparsh'">
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">{{firstName}}</div>
        <p>
            Name :
            <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
        </p>
        <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div  ng-init="names=['Jani','Hege','Kai']">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names">{{x}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/UXTGEWOaRu82WpeOvuOz?p=preview

Comment: yeah its working!! . But as i am new so can you tell me what is the meaning of "Angular only bootstraps the first found application on the page".... what i guess is that it reads only the first ng-app and then ignore all the ng-app in that html page.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Angular will find only the first `ng-app` attribute and kick off template processing, directives/contollers/etc initialization. Any other `ng-app` are not considered.

Comment: hey i made changes accordingly: facing this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29865205/angular-bootstrap-giving-error-in-console/29865704#29865704: please help me.

Answer (score 1):

you can have only one ng-app in html page

so change your code as

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div  ng-init="name='Sparsh'">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">{{firstName}}</div>
    <p>
        Name :
        <input type="text" ng-model="name" />
    </p>
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
</div>
<div  ng-init="names=['Jani','Hege','Kai']">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in names">{{x}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code

```
<div ng-app="" ng-init="names=['Jani','Hege','Kai']">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names">{{x}}</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

does not have an ng-app

ng-repeat only works within an ng-app

Comment: In fact, this is not the problem which causes the ng-repeat to fail. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that only one `ng-app` can be automatically bootstrapped per webpage. So the second `ng-repeat` does not get parsed because it is not contained within an app.

You need to manually bootstrap your apps with `angular.bootstrap()`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap