# Angular : Bootstrap giving error in console

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript" src="./angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    var app1 = angular.module('myApp1', []);
    app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "sparsh";
        $scope.lastName = "khandelwal";
    });
</script>
<title>Home Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-init="name='Sparsh'">
        <div ng-controller="myCtrl">{{firstName}}</div>
        <p>
            Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name">
        </p>
        <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

    </div>
    <div ng-app="myApp1" ng-init="names=['Jani','Hege','Kai']">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="x in names">{{x}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp1','myApp']);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Although i can see the expected output, but at the same time facing console error.

[image]

here is the description of error

(while i click on the url)

[image]

it says it already bootstrapped so i remove the 'myApp' from .bootstrap function, but that didnt work.

Please help.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q13j4weL/2/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Code is working , but giving error in console.

Comment: The fiddle is not giving any error for me - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q13j4weL/3/ - after removing both `ng-app` attributes from the html

Comment: @ArunPJohny if you remove them , how can you say which div is associated with which app ?

Comment: try this approach - http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q13j4weL/5/

Answer (score 1):

You are doing both `ng-app` declarations and `angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp1','myApp']);`.

You need to choose only one method, otherwise you get the well descripted error of multiple bootstrapped applications.

Comment: checked this one 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29864706/angular-ng-repeat-not-working/29864820?noredirect=1#comment47854849_29864820

Comment: @SparshKhandelwal that is in the case if there are multiple ng-app attributes... here you are using auto initialization and manual initialization which is causing the multiple initialization error

Comment: @SparshKhandelwal You might want to do 2 bootstrapping according to element IDs, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/seyenaz/q13j4weL/4/

Comment: @OmriAharon please elaborate it , i am not able to understand : 'here you are using auto initialization and manual initialization which is causing the multiple initialization error'

Comment: You need to either declare `ng-app="myApp"` or `angular.bootstrap(..)`, not both. These are 2 ways to bootstrap, you have to choose one.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is as explained in the previous comments, the automatic and manual initialization of modules.

Since you want to initialize them separately for each elements then try an approach like

```
<div data-app="myApp" ng-init="name='Sparsh'">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">{{firstName}}</div>
    <p>
        Name : <input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
    </p>
    <h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>

</div>
<div data-app="myApp1" ng-init="names=['Jani','Hege','Kai']">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in names">{{x}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

then

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
var app1 = angular.module('myApp1', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.firstName = "sparsh";
    $scope.lastName = "khandelwal";
});

var els = document.querySelectorAll('[data-app]');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    angular.bootstrap(els[i], [els[i].dataset.app]);
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/q13j4weL/)

Comment: @SparshKhandelwal ar you sure it is the same as the fiddle.. because there is no error in the fiddle.. can you post the error message... did you rename `ng-app` to `data-app`

Comment: i missed that :) now working, but what is difference between data-app and ng-app.? and please elaborate this : 'the automatic and manual initialization of modules '

Comment: change it from ng-app to data-app is like removing ng-app .....instead of data-app .. write anything or simply remove it ... everything will work